# How to find the pixel location of a GPS point in an orthoimage with known orientation and GPS location

Tags: image, matlab, gps, coordinates, gis

I have a problem where I need to determine whether a given latitude, longitude GPS-point is in a given orthoimage (approx. 1 hectare area) with known real-world orientation and GPS-location (corresponding to the center of image).

That is, given a GPS-point P, I need to determine:

1. Is point P located in the orthoimage, and if yes,
2. What is the pixel location of point P in the orthoimage.

My question is summarized in the following image:

[image]

As you can see in the image, I know the GPS-coordinates of the image (center) and where North is located with respect to the image. Also, I know how many centimeters in the ground each pixel corresponds to.

**My question is:** What would be an efficient and smart way to achieve the goals in my problem?

One approach I had in mind was to solve a linear mapping between the GPS- and pixel-points and then use this mapping to answer both problems 1-2. I thought this could be a reasonable approach, even though the earth has curvature and the GPS-coordinates are (I'd say) more like a parabolic function of the pixel coordinates, since the distances are very small (one image is an approximately 1 hectare area) I could assume without significant loss in accuracy that the GPS-coordinates change locally linearly w.r.t pixel coordinates.

What do you think? Thank you.

Update:

The orthophotos have been taken with a Phantom 4 Pro drone with gimbal camera system.

Comment: Answering the second question would clearly answer the first assuming no overflows, but it may be so much easier to answer the first question if you know the GPS position of each corner of the image - a simple rectanglular throw-out.

Comment: @GemTaylor Thank you for your help, yes I do not know the corner coordinates, these have to be calculated from the given information.

Comment: On hectare scale, the Earth curvature is rather irrelevant, any topography will have a stronger effect. Given you have the location of the centre, as well as pixel size and number of pixels, calculating the location of the corners is trivial and very fast. What is the problem you are facing with implementing this?

Comment: True, altitude is a bigger issue within the image area if the ortho image was taken with any angle. Do you have the GPS location of the protographer as well to make a pyramoid?

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes, I do. Adriaan, I have no problem, just wanted to know better ideas how to implement this, and whether my approach is valid or not. If you can, I would appreciate if you could provide a high-level pseudocode.

Comment: Hi @Adriaan thank you for your message, could you elaborate a bit more how you would implement your approach. I'm not 100% what you would do with the corners in a general case where the GPS-coordinate axes can be arbitrary w.r.t the image. This might be new to me. In a case where the GPS- and pixel coordinate axes would be parallel, I agree this problem would indeed be trivial.

Comment: You can use a simple rotation matrix to rotate coordinates to whatever convenient frame. I.e. simply calculate vertical and horizontal distances of your corners wrt the centre, then rotate to the north (probably)

Comment: You may want to start with a huge circular discard based on whatever gps you have before doing any " real math". If the target is 200 miles away from the camera, then it clearly isn't on the photo :-) Next, you could find the corners and construct planes for the sides of the pyramidoid, and the target must be inside each plane. Now, you can rotate the target into the plane of the viewpoint centreline, or perhaps use the viewpoint diagonals as axes if the picture is square?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I will take these suggestions into consideration :) @GemTaylor The image is not a square, but a rectangle with a 3:2 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about one possibility myself, not perfect but it's a start:

The following information is given:

a rectangular orthoimage `Img`, `Yaw` of the image (that is, how many degrees the image is facing away from north), `pix_size` pixel size in the ground (centimeters/pixel).

The problem is: Given an arbitrary GPS-point `p = (lat, long)`, determine the pixel location of `p` in `Img`.

Denote `c = (latc, longc)` and `cp = (x,y)` as the GPS- and pixel-coordinates of the center point of `Img`.

Determine how much we must move along North-South and West-East axes to get from `c` to `p`. Let `lat_delta = latc-lat` and `long_delta = longc-long`. If `lat_delta < 0` -> `p` is more in north than `c`, otherwise `p` is more in south than `c`. The same goes analoguously for `long_delta`.

```
>     if lat_delta < 0:
>         pN = [latc + abs(lat_delta), longc]        
>     else:
>         pN = [latc - abs(lat_delta), longc] 
> 
>     if lat_long < 0:
>         pE = [latc, longc + abs(long_delta)]        
>     else:
>         pE = [latc, longc - abs(long_delta)]
```

Now the points `c, p, pN` and `pE` form a "spherical" right triangle (I think I could safely assume it to be planar because the orthophoto describes max 1 hectare area). So the Pythagorean theorem applies sufficiently enough for my purposes.

Next, I calculate the ground distances `dN = Haversine(c,pN)` and `dE = Haversine(c, pE)`, which tell me how much in ground distance I must move in North-South and West-East axes in order to get from `c` to `p`.

Now I will apply a rotation matrix `R(-Yaw)` to vectors `n = [0,1]` and `e = [1,0]`, which represent the upwards and right vectors in my pixel coordinate system. So I get `nr = R(-Yaw)*n` and `er = R(-Yaw)*e` where `nr` is a unit pixel vector pointing towards North in the image and `er` is similarly a unit pixel vector pointing towards East in the image.

Next, I calculate the ratios mN = dN/pix_size and mE = dE/pix_size (the factors also need to take into account the +- direction). Now I calculate the pixel location of `p` by:

> `pp = cp + mN*nr + mE*er,`

where I can now easily check if the pixel values `pp` are within the bounds of the image `Img`.

Of course this method does not work in a general large area case and needs to be refined for this purpose.

Comment: This method worked for my purposes (field images). I'd be happy though to have a better and more general way of doing this.